# Msfvenom encode with no payload

Tags: linux, metasploit, msfvenom

is it possible to just encode an elf executable using the encoders and still end up with a working 'packed' executable? or am i misunderstanding what an encoder is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the msfvenom encoder can only encode shellcode. Encoding an PE would be different because it requires a stub (decrypter) and [loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)). A crypter or packer is what you're looking for.

For a more detailed description of how crypters work: https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/18849.pdf